# Ruby Rails Cron Scheduler without cron process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a ruby gem that provides cron-like behaviour triggered by page-loads (rather than a background process)?

Update: I'm looking for something that works like this : https://drupal.org/project/poormanscron

Comment: This sounds kind of vague... What are you trying to do?

Comment: Updated with a link to equivalent project for drupal

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` to call a method on every page-hit.

But scheduling different tasks at different times is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out whenever 
https://github.com/javan/whenever

It creates cron jobs for you with ruby syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I created https://github.com/Ebbe/arask

No need to install anything (other than the gem) or setup anything outside of rails. No background process, except for the actual job.

Add `gem 'arask'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, `rails generate arask:install` and `rails db:migrate`.

Now you can setup your tasks in the file config/initializers/arask.rb:

```
arask.create script: 'puts "IM ALIVE!"', interval: :daily
arask.create task: 'my:awesome_task', interval: :hourly
arask.create task: 'my:other_awesome_task', interval: 2.hours
```

The tasks will automatically run if the server is running.